# THREE.js spotlight casting shadow with no object between the near plane and the receiver

Tags: three.js

I'm having troubles with getting shadows to work in [three.js](/questions/tagged/three.js) . On the image below you can see a spotlight casting a shadow on an object with plane geometries. There is no object in between the spotlight near plane and the plane geometries of the wall.

What can cause such behavior?

[image: Three.js spotlight]

The light is configured this way:

```
var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xFFFFFF, 1);
spotLight.position.set(0, -20, 100);
spotLight.target.position.set(0,0,0);
spotLight.shadowDarkness = 0.5;
spotLight.shadowCameraVisible = true;
spotLight.castShadow = true;
spotLight.shadowMapWidth = 1024;
spotLight.shadowMapHeight = 1024;

spotLight.shadowCameraNear = 10;
spotLight.shadowCameraFar = 200;
spotLight.shadowCameraFov = 10;
spotLight.shadowBias = 0.1;
scene.add(spotLight);
```

The rectangular meshes are `BufferGeometries` converted from `PlaneGeometries`  with an png uv mapped image as the texture with `.receiveShadow` set to `true`.

THREE.js version r71.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is self-shadowing, try to play with `spotLight.shadowBias`. Usually, a value of 0.05 is used for avoid self-shadowing.

Comment: thanks @Ale_32, changing the value of `.shadowBias` moves the self-shadow halfway up or down, doesn't make it disappear... I've read it has something to do with the `.shadowCameraFov` value being too small... so, it means that you cannot create a small lamp without that self-shadow artifact?

Comment: Use a small _negative_ value for `.shadowBias` to alleviate self-shadowing artifacts in this case.

Comment: You can try also -0.05 as value... Or you can increase z-precision of shadowmap reducing size of light frustum